# Burning the Challah portion

Tags: separating-challah

What is a practical way of burning the Challah portion that is removed from dough? Wrapping it in foil and leaving it in the oven would produce too much smoke for my house.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the foil or the above mentioned grill you can also sear it on a stove top burner.  Alternately since it is so small simply place it in the oven while cooking the loaves.  It need not be reduced to a cinder, simply rendered inedible.  If you are getting smoke you have typically already passed the point of it being "burnt" and now you are starting to carbonize it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a problem of "reycha" to bake it together with other loaves?

Comment: Reycha is milsa only if there is zey'a.

Comment: Are sure about that? I thought that reycha is prohibited only l'chatchila, while zey'a is prohibited even b'di'avad.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the reycha is not an issue here, as essentially this is the method laid out by the Ben Ish Hai... sorry don't remember the parsha or ot.

Comment: This is from the OU's website:

 **May I use my oven while the Challah is burning?** If the challah is completely wrapped up, one may bake other items in the oven while the challah is burning. However, if the challah is uncovered, it is best to avoid baking anything else in the oven while the challah is burning. [Footnote -The Shach (Yoreh Deah 108:1) quotes from the Issur V’heter that one may bake bread in the oven while the challah is burning. However, the Aruch Ha’shulchan (108:9) and others disagree and feel that the oven should not be used at all if the challah is uncovered.] ...

Comment: [cont.]... If one accidentally did use the oven while the challah was burning, one may eat the food. [Footnote - See Rema Yoreh Deah 108:1.]  
  
From http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/8981

Comment: Well the Rama does not comment at all on Halah:
הגה: ד ה] וה"ה לבשר עם חלב נמי דינא הכי. (טור סימן צ"ז). ו] ונוהגין להחמיר לכתחלה, אפילו בתנור גדול; <ג> ובדיעבד, להקל אפילו בתנור קטן. (ארוך כלל ל"ט ובתשובת ר"י מינץ ובהגהת ש"ד ואגור בשם מהרי"ל וטור בשם רשב"א שכן הסכמת רוב המורים והוא שיטת רש"י וה"ג ורי"ף ורמב"ם). ה ז] ואם אפה פת עם בשר, אסור לאכלו עם חלב, אם יש לו פת אחר (שם). ח] וכן אם עובד כוכבים אפה פת עם איסור, ו אסור לקנות אותו פת אם יש פת אחר, דכל זה מקרי לכתחלה. אבל אם אין לו פת אחר בריוח, ט] מותר בשניהם, <ד> דזה מקרי לענין זה דיעבד. (אגור בשם ר"י מולין).

Comment: ח יא] ובמקום הפסד אין להחמיר, בדיעבד (כי כן נראה מהפוסקים וכ"פ ב"י), אפילו סתום לגמרי. ט יב] ואם האיסור דבר חריף, יג] וכל שכן אם ההיתר דבר חריף, ריחא מלתא היא <ה> ואפילו בדיעבד אסור, אם שניהם מגולים. יד] אבל אם אחד מהם מכוסה, י אפילו בבצק בעלמא, מותר. (מרדכי פ' ג"ה ואו"ה). טו] אם אפו או צלאו איסור והיתר תחת מחבת אחת, מגולין, אסור (תוספות) אפילו בדיעבד (שם בארוך). טז] וה"ה אם אפו בכה"ג פת עם בשר, יא אסור לאכלו בחלב (ש"ד סימן ס' ומהרא"י). יז] יב אבל (ב) בזה אחר זה אין לחוש (תשובת מיי' סוף הלכה מ"א ותשובת ר"י ואו"ה), יח] אלא אם כן הזיע המחבת משניהם,

Comment: דאז אסור אפילו בזה אחר זה, אם היו שניהם מגולין, דהוי ככיסוי של קדרה. (ד"ע ממשמעות הרא"ש סימן צ"ג, כדלעיל סימן צ"ג). יג י"א דכל מקום דאמרינן ריחא מילתא ואוסר בדיעבד, היינו דוקא דליכא ששים מן ההיתר נגד האיסור. אבל בדאיכא ששים מן ההיתר, <ו> אפי' בכל מה שבתנור, מבטל האיסור. (שם בארוך כלל ל"ט די"ח). יט] ולצורך הפסד יש לנהוג כן. כ] י"א דאיסור האוסר במשהו, כגון חמץ בפסח, ריחא מלתא ואוסר אפילו בדיעבד, כא] יד אם התנור קטן והוא סתום, והאיסור וההיתר מגולין תוך התנור.

Comment: (ד"מ בשם הגהת סמ"ק ובשם תוספות עבודת כוכבים דף ס"ו ע"ב). טו כב] ויש אומרים שאין לחלק. (ד"מ בשם מרדכי). ובמקום הפסד יש לסמוך אדברי המקילין. ועיין לקמן סוף סימן קי"ח אם יש להחמיר לכתחלה לשפות ב' קדירות, וא' מהן של איסור, על הכירה או לצלות איסור אצל היתר.

Comment: The Shakh only briefly discusses it at the end of his comment:
גם באו"ה כלל ל"ט דין כ"ד כתב דחלה שלנו שהיא מדרבנן מותר לכתחלה לאפות עם הפת עכ"ל משמע דאיסור דאורייתא כחוש אסור לכתחלה וז"א והכי מוכח נמי להדיא מתשובת ר"ת וראבי"ה שבש"ד סי' ל"ו ובתשו' מיימוני המ"א סי"ו ובמרדכי פכ"ש וברוקח סי' רצ"ב ע"ש וכ"נ מדברי מהרש"ל פג"ה סימן ט"ו וע"ש:

The idea is that without a Temple in Eretz Yisrael, and in all of Hutz La'Aretz since Hala is only M'D'Rabbannan there should be no problem.

Comment: The cited Arukh HaShulhan also is only speaking of cooking an unkosher meat with a kosher product:
כל הגדולים הסכימו דאפילו לשיטת האוסרים בבשר שחוטה ובשר נבלה שצלאו יחד וכן לשיטת המתירים מיהו לכתחלה אסור כמו שנתבאר זהו הכל כשאחד מהם שמן אבל בשניהם כחושים מותר אף לכתחלה [ט"ז וש"ך סק"א ופר"ח וכרו"פ ע"ש]

Comment: ולענ"ד לא נראה כן מלשון הרמב"ם שם שכתב אין צולין בשר שחוטה עם בשר נבלה וכו' ואם צלאן ה"ז מותר ואפילו היתה האסורה שמינה הרבה וכו' עכ"ל
הרי דלענין לכתחלה לא הזכיר כלל כחוש ושמן וכן בירושלמי שהבאנו אומר סתם מהו לצלות בשר שחוטה עם בשר נבלה ולא הזכיר כלל כחוש ושמן וגם מפסחים שם משמע להדיא כן שהרי הקשה הש"ס על מי שאוסר מהא דתניא אין צולין שני פסחים כאחד כדי שלא יתערבו הגופין זה בזה ויאכלו הפסח שלא למנוייו ולדברי האוסר הא גם בלא זה אסור מפני שזה בולע מזה ע"י הריח ונדחק הש"ס למצא תירוצים ע"ש ואם כדברי רבותינו אין כאן קושיא כלל דאיצטריך להיכא דשניהם כחושים אלא ודאי דגם בכה"ג אסור לכתחלה והאי

Comment: דמפרש הש"ס שם למאן דאסר אפילו בשר שחוטה שמן ובשר נבלה כחוש ע"ש זהו לענין דיעבד דבכה"ג גם בדיעבד אסור ובשניהם כחושים מותר בדיעבד אבל לכתחלה גם בשניהם כחושים אסור וכן משמע בשערי דורא סי' ל"ה שכתב בזה"ל אבל מיני בשר דמפטמא מודה דלכתחלה מיהא אסור ע"ש שלא הזכיר כחוש ושמן

Answer (score 6):

My wife usually just saves them throughout the year, and then I burn them with the chametz.

Comment: I assume you keep them in the freezer (or in formaldehyde). The problem with saving them is the concern of תקלה (if it's not destroyed, someone might use it).

Comment: @Dave: yeah, in the freezer. They're lumps of dough; it's not that likely that someone is going to go and eat them by mistake.

Comment: So would you think it's ok to keep it in the freezer for 5 years? 20 years? If the halacha is to burn it, logically you should do so as soon as possible. If keeping it in the freezer is good enough, you should be able to keep it there (or anywhere, for that matter) forever. It's not like this is some kind of "mitzvas sreifah" that you perform whenever you're in the mood.

Comment: @Dave, I guess then the question is whether indeed the halachah is that it must be burned and there's no other alternative, or whether perhaps that's just the fallback position because we have no kohen to eat it. I see where Aruch Hashulchan 322:10 mentions a case of challah from chutz la'aretz that was brought into E.Y., where indeed one should wait till erev Pesach to burn it with the chametz, because to do so earlier would be degrading to it. Granted that we don't apply that rationale in the usual case, that still may indicate that there's no overarching mitzvah to burn it immediately.

Comment: @Alex besides, perhaps we will have efer parah before next biur chametz, and some lucky cohen will get to eat it!

Comment: @هه: amen! But they still wouldn't be able to eat it then, because the challah itself has become tamei (and there's no way to make foods or drinks tahor after they become tamei, except water).

Comment: @Alex But they could derive benefit from it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not in E. Israel, you can bake it and give it to a Sepharadic Cohen who dipped in a mikveh. (Shulchan Aruch YO"D [322:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=294)-[5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=295))

Comment: or a katan below 9.

Comment: Is it that a ashkenazi can give it to a sephardi kohein, or a sephardi could give it to an ashkenazi kohein? Ie is the ashkenazi minhag an issur of giving or receiving?

Comment: Couldn't you also give it to a Kohein's wife whilst she is pure?

Answer (score 2):

Find someone with an outdoor grill, and put it under the metal, with the coals (or natural-gas briquette thingies).

Comment: How long would that typically take?  I once tried something like that and it took forever (~1.5 hours).

Answer (score 1):

If you live in a place with enough sun, consider putting a small 'solar cooker' on a window sill (or porch, if you have one).  Consider whether the (albeit brief) smoking will draw concern and attention.

[Solar cookers can even be built make-shift](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar+cooker+plans&aq=0&oq=solar+cooker+&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), if you need.

Comment: Cool! (So to speak...)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10462/759

Answer (score 1):

If you can't handle the smoke, get it out of your kitchen! That is, tell your local Kohein that you hold like [Maharam of Rothenburg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg) who, as quoted in [Sefer HaParnas](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9386&st=&pgnum=22) (written by one of his students) [111](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9386&st=&pgnum=22), was particular to burn the separated Challah portion in the house of a Kohein only. So now, dealing with the excess smoke is his <s>problem</s> <s>burden</s> familial responsibility.