# Bal Tashchit and Chametz

Tags: halacha, chametz-leaven, bal-tashchit-waste

Before Pesach, it is common to attempt to get rid of whatever chametzdik food one is able to. Taking this and the *issur* (prohibition) of bal tashchit into account, is it actually permissible to throw out and/or burn chametz that is still edible, rather than selling it?

CYLOR

Comment: If one holds that one should not sell chametz gamur then they should make a chesbon to try to finish all their chmatez beforehand,

Comment: Chametz on Pesach is value-less. You aren't destroying anything of value.

Comment: @DoubleAA Technically, when you destroy it, it has value. But I agree with your comment anyway. Case in point: Rav... Shteinman I think?... someone, anyway, was asked about a _baal t'shuva_'s stealing his parent's _chametz_ before _Pesach_ (in a manner that would effect a change in ownership) so as to prevent his parent from owning it on _Pesach_, and then selling it to a non-Jew, and replied that, as the _chametz_ would become worthless if not stolen, the theft was effectively _meshiv aveda_ (returning a lost object, i.e., here, saving an object from being lost).

Comment: related answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16323/1362

Answer (score 3):

I have always had this question as well, and I recently found an answer:)

In Yabia Omer Chelek Even Haezer 4:9 אות ד Rav Ovadia discusses how the custom of breaking the cup at the wedding is not bal tashchit since there is a purpose for it and bal tashchit doesnt apply to that minhag, since whenever we have a reason for the action, bal tashchit doesn't apply. The same thing he writes in Yechaveh Daat 5:46 where he discusses if cutting branches of a tree that produces fruit for the schach is bal tashchit. He answers that it is not bal tashchit because again it has a reason, and it is a mitzvah, and therefore bal tashchit doesn't apply in those situations.

I would say the same thing here: Since the Torah tells us to get rid of the chametz and therefore we have a reason, bal tashchit doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57081/bal-tashchit-and-chametz#comment153181_57084

Comment: Same thing (even for a minhag) with overflowing a cup of wine

Comment: This doesn't excuse having lots of chametz sitting around that needs to be destroyed. The issur was when you got pizza take-out when you still had 10 boxes of pasta in the cabinet. You're right that once you get to erev pesach you have to destroy the pasta, but it was wrong to put yourself in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

עשה דוחה לא תעשה - The biblical commandment to destroy all the leaven in one's possession overrides the general prohibition of *bal tashchit*. According to Rabbi Yehuda - which I believe is how Rashi rules - the *mitzva* of *biur chametz* is by burning. In fact, the general custom is to burn the last remains of *chametz*.

Comment: I would imagine that this would not fall under bal tashchit in the first place, since bal tashchit is likely defined as destruction for no purpose, whereas here the destruction is for the purpose of fulfilling a mitzvah; thus there would be no necessity to invoke עשה דוחה לא תעשה

Comment: fair enough....